# Using curl to request for Amadeus API access token

Tags: php, api, curl, access-token, amadeus

I'm trying to request an access token using a PHP script. I'm using curl to post my API key and secret and expecting to receive a JSON response which includes an access token. I'm failing (I don't get a response). Am I missing something in my code? 
I would have prefered to use an SDK but Amadeus does not have one for php.

```
$url = ' https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token';
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curls,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={id number}&client_secret={secret}');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$token = curl_exec($curls);
curl_close($curls);
print_r ($token);
```

Comment: [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) is your friend.

Comment: Kindly make sure that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` dont require to be json_encoded

Comment: `curl_error($curls)` should tell you what went wrong

Comment: Thank you guys, your inputs really helped me reach a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space before your url at the first line.

You can remove some lines as well:

```
$url = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token';
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=API_KEY&client_secret=API_SECRET');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$token = curl_exec($curls);
curl_close($curls);
print_r ($token);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The extra space was one of the problems in my code. As you also mentioned about having redundant lines, my second (and last problem) was on line 6. After I commented out the line 6, it worked :)